# How to find a element inside a DIV with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to find a way to get the value of a div, but I can not find the element either by Xpath or by cssSelector. In both cases (Xpath and cssSelector), the Eclipse console displays the error message:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//b[text()='Protocolo Ãšnico ']/following::span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JZa6.jpg)"}

Using the xpath, I can find the value I need but, I can not get it and play in a variable. Below is the image with the HTML of the page and the xpath I made.

[image: Xpath]
I've created a method called **verifyTextAssert** that takes a **By** parameter and returns the text. The method below follows:

```
public String verifyTextAssert(By by) {

    return driver.findElement(by).getText();

}
```

In the **TratOsFatRoamPage** class I created the **getNuPu** method that calls the **verifyTextAssert** method and passes the xpath to this method and should return the found value.

```
private String obterNuPu() {

    return verifyTextAssert(By.xpath("//b[text()='Protocolo Único ']/following::span[1]")); 

}
```

[image]

```html
<fieldset style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <div id="content_titulo">Informações Gerais</div>
    <div style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left:5px; height:150%;">
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">ID Atendimento </b> <br> <span>5574474205</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Protocolo Único </b> <br> <span>2018227017094</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"><b class="label_tratamento ">Data Abertura </b> <br> <span>21/03/2018</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Hora Abertura </b> <br> <span></span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"><b class="label_tratamento ">Nome do Cliente </b> <br> <span></span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Tipo Cliente </b> <br> <span></span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Motivo 1 </b> <br> <span>Reclamação</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Motivo 2 </b> <br> <span>Claro Conta</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Motivo 3 </b> <br> <span>Contestação</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Motivo 4 </b> <br> <span>Serviços</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Motivo 5 </b> <br> <span>Pacote de Internet</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Worklist </b> <br> <span>BackOfficeAjusteRoaming GE</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">CNPJ </b> <br> <span>19988702272</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">MSISDN </b> <br> <span>69993932002</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">MSISDN2 </b> <br> <span></span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Status PS8 </b> <br> <span>Pendente</span></div>
        <div style="float:left; width:24%; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left:5px; height:30px; font-size:x-small;"> <b class="label_tratamento ">Quem Abriu </b> <br> <span></span></div><input type="hidden" name="Id_Estrategia_Logado" id="Id_Estrategia_Logado" value="359"><input type="hidden" name="Id_Atividade_Logado" id="Id_Atividade_Logado" value="0">

    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Seems like there is an frame/iframe involved. Please check for frame and update us.

Comment: Cruisepandey, It is inside a fieldset tag. I updated the question with image showing the fieldset.

Comment: When you post HTML and/or code please take a minute to use a beautifier like http://jsbeautifier.org/ or your IDE to properly format everything. If you need help properly formatting it on the site, see the formatting help link in the sidebar of the question editor. It makes it a LOT easier to read which makes your question more likely to get answered. Thanks!

Comment: I think you want the **sibling**: `//b[text()='Protocolo Único ']/following-sibling::span[1]`.

Comment: SiKing, after putting the word sibling, it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use below CSS selector to get the text.

```
 driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3)"));
```

Edit

```
var element =  driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span"));
string v = element.Text;
```

Comment: Prany, Unfortunately, it did not work with CssSelector. The same mistake.  org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > fieldset:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(2) > span:nth-child(3)"}

Comment: @Kakashi-Sensei - Added an answer.could you check?

Comment: Prany, i was able to solve the problem with the answer given by the SiKing user, just above. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `xPath` is correct. The one suggestion is try to find if in your page are `iframes`. If yes, have a look if your element is inside one of them. The second suggestion is to have a look on the element css properties, if there is no "strange" attributes